# Searching for list of chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way I could search for all chrome extensions on Google or may be able to search extensions based on chrome extension icons?

Comment: What do you want to do here? Do you want to search all your installed chrome extensions in chrome store?

Comment: No, not installed on mine. Just all the chrome extensions available on chrome store as of latest date @ArchitGarg